# Create new quote item instead of updating existing quote item for same product

Tags: magento-enterprise, event-observer

I have created a custom attribute for quote item,order item problematically.
I have added a drop down option with multiple values for all products.(I don't use custom option because my values are dynamic). I am able to save the selected value of drop down in that custom quote item attribute. 
But the issue is, if I select the same product with different custom values (the dropdown value I have added), it's updating the quantity of existing quote item.

I want to create new entry of quote item instead of updating existing quote item entry. On which event quote item updated?
can anyone help me on which event should I add my logic.

Comment: have you send custom attribute value in add to cart  request?

Answer (score 1):

Magento checks if a product is already in the cart (with the same custom options selected) in the method `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item::representProduct`.

notice the last 2 `if` statements

```
if (!$this->compareOptions($itemOptions, $productOptions)) {
    return false;
}
if (!$this->compareOptions($productOptions, $itemOptions)) {
    return false;
}
```

these 2 check if there is a difference between the options from the quote item and the options from the product.
You need to rewrite this method and add a new verification, to check if your custom field from the product is different from the custom field you already set on the quote item.
If they are different, `return false` and Magento will create a new line in the cart with the same product.
Unfortunately I didn't find any events you can use for this, so I think a rewrite is in order.

Comment: but I have saved this custom option as quote item attribute and it's not part of product attribute